# unicorn server with Ubuntu init script

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, unicorn, init.d

I created this `init.d` script for unicorn according to this [digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the unicorn app server
# Description:       starts unicorn using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

set -e

USAGE="Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|rotate|force-stop>"

# app settings
USER="deploy"
APP_NAME="appname"
APP_ROOT="/home/$USER/$APP_NAME"
ENV="production"

# environment settings
PATH="/home/$USER/.rbenv/shims:/home/$USER/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E $ENV -D"
PID="$APP_ROOT/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
OLD_PID="$PID.oldbin"

# make sure the app exists
cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PID && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PID`
}

case $1 in
  start)
    sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
    echo "Starting $APP_NAME"
    su - $USER -c "$CMD"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping $APP_NAME"
    sig QUIT && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  force-stop)
    echo "Force stopping $APP_NAME"
    sig TERM && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  restart|reload|upgrade)
    sig USR2 && echo "reloaded $APP_NAME" && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
    $CMD
    ;;
  rotate)
    sig USR1 && echo rotated logs OK && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't rotate logs" && exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    echo >&2 $USAGE
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Now (the script's name is `uicorn_app`)

```
sudo update-rc.d `unicorn_app` defaults
```

works. But whenever i try

```
 $ sudo service unicorn_app start
 Starting app
 -su bundle: command not found
```

However i am able to stop it via

```
$ sudo service unicorn_app stop
```

after i started it manually with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s -b ip.ip.ip.ip
```

I installed `ruby on rails` on `/etc/local` via rbenv and the `PATH` 
first entries redirect to the proper directories:

```
/usr/local/rbenv/shims
/usr/lcoal/rbenv/bin
```

What do i need to change that my scripts finds bundle? Since i think the PATH is correct what else could go wrong? Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the solution was to do with the rbenv installation. I needed to add the lines `PATH` and `RBENV_ROOT` to my ~/.bash_profile. After adding them there i was able to start unicorn via `sudo service unicorn_app start`